# Python pandas Quantile Data Analysis

Tags: pandas, data-analysis

Can anyone explain what is Quantile ([]) in pandas?
What is the use of that?
 Example:df["DebtRatio"].quantile(0.975)

what does Quantile(0.975) do here?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html

Answer (score 0):

It returns a value such that the smallest 97.5% elements in the df["DebtRatio"] are less than this value.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(1,1001), columns=['DebtRatio'])

df.DebtRatio.quantile(0.975)

975.025
```